# Difference between msys2.exe and mingw64.exe in MSYS installation

Tags: mingw, msys, msys2

I have an MSYS installation on my Windows machine.

Inside the root folder, there are two executables:

- msys2.exe
- mingw64.exe

(There is also a mingw32.exe but that is just the 32-bit version of mingw64, I believe).

Both executables launch a terminal window, that seem identical to me, apart from the fact that $PATH reports slight differences.

What is the difference between these two, and what is the purpose of each?

Comment: IIRC, packages in the msys2 repo relies on `msys-runtime`, which is a `POSIX emulation engine` (a bit like a libc but in the form of a translation layer, I think) forked from  Cygwin, to work, while MINGW packages are more or less compiled as native Windows programs / libraries.